# not able to show array or object of data in tabluar form

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have fetched data from nodejs and want to show that object of data in react js (Table form).

Data fetched from backend

[image: data fetched from backend]

[image: output screen shot]

I want to display this data in table format.

```
<table className="table">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th scope="col">Row Number</th>
                      <th scope="col">Order Number</th>
                      <th scope="col">Error Description</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>

                  <tbody>
                  {/* <tr >
                      
                     {errorresult.map((item, index) => (
                       <div  key={index}>
                        {Object.keys(item[index]).map((subarr, i) => (
                          
                            <td key={i}>{item[subarr]}</td>
                          
                        ))}
                     </div>
                    ))} </tr>  */}
                          <tr>
                    {Object.keys(errorresult).map((item, i) => (
                   
                    
                        <td key={i}>{errorresult[item]}</td>
                        
                    
                      ))}</tr> 
                  </tbody>
                </table>
```

Guys, please help, I have used the map function to display data but am not able to show data in different rows. In my code, all data show in one row.

Answer (score 0):

Inside the loop you are using only *td* , that means it will insert the data only in columns of a single row. If you want to fix the issue the row **tr** also be inside loop.

Comment: thanks, I have set tr inside loop then all output comes under only the first column.

Comment: you should handle it inside your loop. Just a simple logic. You can add any number of td as per your wish. If there is one td then there is a single column